Upper bound on the Levy-Prokhorov distance between the distributions of continuous Gaussian processes in terms of their covariances
Denote by $d$ the supremum metric on the space $C[0,T]$ of continuous real-valued functions on $[0,T]$:
$$
d(f,g) = \sup_{t \in [0,T]} |f(t)-g(t)|.
$$
Let $\rho$ be the Levy-Prokhorov metric on the space of probability measures on the metric space $M=(C[0,T],d)$.
Given two continuous Gaussian processes $X(t), t \in [0,T]$ and $Y(t), t \in [0,T]$ with mean functions $m_X(t)=\mathbb{E}X(t)$, $m_Y(t)=\mathbb{E}Y(t)$ and covariance functions $R_X(t,s)=\mathbb{E} X(t)X(s),\,R_Y(t,s)=\mathbb{E} Y(t)Y(s)$ is there a known upper bound on $\rho(P_X,P_Y)$ in terms of $m_X(t),m_Y(t),R_X(t,s),R_Y(t,s)$, where $P_X$ and $P_Y$ are the distributions of $X$ and $Y$ (as probability measures on $C[0,T]$) respectively?

One potential approach is to use the comparison with Wasserstein distance (as mentioned here ON CHOOSING AND BOUNDING PROBABILITY METRICS)
$$(d_{P} )^{ 2} \leq d_{W} \leq 2 d_{P}.$$
And use the explicit formula for Gaussian processes in the Wasserstein distance as mentioned here Learning from uncertain curves: The 2-Wasserstein metric for Gaussian processes
$$W^2_{2} (\mu_1, \mu_2) = d^{2}_{2} (m_1, m_2) + Tr (K_1 + K_2 − 2(K_1^{1/2}  K_{2}K_{1}^{1/2})^{1/2}),$$
where $m_1,m_2,K_1,K_2$ are the mean and covariance operators for the Gaussian processes $X_1,X_2$ and $\mu_{1},\mu_{2}$ are the corresponding measures on $L^{2}([0,T])$ with metric $d_{2}$. As mentioned in the article, the key idea is
As the sample paths of $f_1$ and $f_2$ are in $H=L^{2}([0,T])$, they induce Gaussian measures  $\mu_{1},\mu_{2} \in P_2(H)$ on $H$, as there is a 1-1 correspondence between GPs having sample paths almost surely on a $L^{2}([0,T])$ space and Gaussian measures on $L^{2}([0,T])$.

Thank you very much! However, my metric is different from the metric bounded by this approach. Suppose that $f_1$, $f_2$ are continuous GPs on compact $X \subset R^n$. On the space of continuous functions $C(X)$  there are two metrics: $d_1(f,g)=\sup_{x \in X} |f(x)-g(x)|$ and $d_2(f,g)=(\int_X |f(x)-g(x)|^2 dx)^{1/2}$. What they estimate is $W_2(f_1,f_2)=\inf (\mathbb{E}[d_2(X,Y)]^2)^{1/2}$, where the infimum is taken over all $(X,Y)$ with $X$ distributed as $f_1$ and $Y$ distributed as $f_2$, while my metric can be bounded (from $(d_P)^2\leq d_W \leq d_P$) by $\inf \mathbb{E}[d_1(X,Y)]$.

@ssssnnnn Maybe I misunderstanding your question. But the 1-Wass and 2-Wass are comparable eg. see https://lchizat.github.io/files2020ot/lecture3.pdf

Yes, indeed, it is not much of a problem to pass from 1-Wass to 2-Wass and backwards. But what I need is the Wasserstein metric which corresponds to the metric space $(C[0,1],d_1)$ with $d_1$ being the supremum metric, and what they estimate, for example, is the Wasserstein metric which corresponds to $(L^2([0,1]),d_2)$ with d_2 being the L^2 metric; since d_2 can be much smaller than d_1, an upper bound on the Wasserstein distance corresponding to d_2 does not necessarily provide an upper bound on the Wasserstein distance corresponding to d_1

@ssssnnnn I see. Well then it doesn't seem possible to get a bound with covariances to show up because the covariance are an L2-type object not a supremum-type object.
